# poblema mongoose aggregate

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

estoy tratando de crear un aggregate usando mongoose version 5.x al hacerlo me devuelve el siguiente error

> Mongoose 5.x disallows passing a spread of operators to
>   'Model.aggregate()'. Instead of `Model.aggregate({ $match }, { $skip
>   })', do 'Model.aggregate([{ $match }, { $skip }])

el código que estoy usando para crear el aggregate es el siguiente

```
  eventos.aggregate(
  { "$match": { "fecha": f } },
    {
      "$lookup":
        {
          "from": "usuarios",
          "localField": "googleId",
          "foreignField": "googleId",
          "as": "user"
        }
    },
    { "$unwind": "$user" }

    ,function (err, evento) {
    if (err){
      return handleError(err);
    } else{

      console.log(evento);
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

la solucion que encontre fue estructurar como pipeline y ya funciona como es debido.

```
 eventos.aggregate().
match({ "fecha": f }).
lookup( {
  "from": "usuarios",
  "localField": "googleId",
  "foreignField": "googleId",
  "as": "user"
}).
unwind("$user").
exec(function (err, evento) {
  if (err){
    return handleError(err);
  } else{
    res.json({code:201,events:evento});
    console.log(evento);
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Parece que el error te dice que no has puesto los corchetes (**[ ]**) en la función. No se si tiene otro error pero lo que te pide es hacer lo siguiente:

```
eventos.aggregate([ //Aquí lo abro
  { "$match": { "fecha": f } },
    {
      "$lookup":
        {
          "from": "usuarios",
          "localField": "googleId",
          "foreignField": "googleId",
          "as": "user"
        }
    },
    { "$unwind": "$user" }] //Aquí cierro
    ,function (err, evento) {
        if (err){
          return handleError(err);
        } else{

          console.log(evento);
        }
    });
```

Un saludo

Comment: realice lo que me indicaste pero aun asi me pedía que lo estructurara como pipeline lo realice de esta manera y funciono correctamente